# Vent problem? I think

Tags: plumbing

Our kitchen sink was draining slow and slower and then nothing. Trying find the clog, at some point we took the vent off (next to or under sink, not roof) and it drains perfect. Put the vent back on and it's plugged up again, take the vent off and it drains great. Already got a new vent thinking that was  the problem, installed it and same problem as above

Comment: What are you taking off, exactly? Photos would help.

Comment: Is this a one basin sink? A dishwasher present?

Comment: I assume you're talking about removing and reconnecting an air admittance valve (aka cheater vent). If that's appearing to fix your clog, consider the possibility that what you're doing by removing it is allowing air to exit the drain/vent pipes and just letting waste that can't flow down the drain flow up into your vent pipe a bit instead. You can test that a bit by using your hand to cover the area where the aav attached and pouring some water down. My guess is you'll feel pressure, not vacuum, and you still have a clog downstream.

Comment: Double sink and no dishwasher.

Comment: I'm not sure what it called exactly, it has a rubber flapper thing inside and is attached like a vent, so that what I thought it was haha

Comment: Shimon- if there is pressure then there is a clog still? If there's a vaccum there's not?

Comment: Sounds like an air admittance valve. You can probably find a model number and Google it to confirm. These devices are supposed to let air into the pipe but not out. If the device is working properly and removing it helps, that means letting pressure out is helping, which probably means you've still got a clog and all you're  doing when removing the vent is letting some of your waste water get stored temporarily in the vent pipes. If you feel a vacuum that is where the aav should be letting air in to relieve that.